# How to add multi-language support to opencart module

Tags: php, module, opencart, multilingual

I've gotten pretty good at creating my own vqmods and it has allowed me to customize the cart to my heart's content. I am now at a point where I want to start supporting the other official language in my country.

I've searched and searched plus looked as some modules on the opencart extension store but still can't quite get a grasp on it. There are no posts that I could find in the support forums explaining how to go about achieving this. I have a module that creates a new tab on the product page. On this tab, I have use ckeditor to format the text and all works well.

I've seen it done where you go into a module to customize it and you can see extra buttons to add text for different languages. Just can't find any free modules that uses this so that I could muddle my way through making it work.

Can anyone help me to add multilanguage to my custom opencart modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by looking at another mod with language files in it.